# Adding scroll bar to windows forms, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I need to add scroll horizontal and vertical scroll bar. The problem is that they doesn't work, as in when I use them the screen doesn't move.

```
VScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
HScrollBar hScrollBar1 = new HScrollBar();

vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
hScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
Controls.Add(hScrollBar1);
```

I use the code to add scroll bars, how do I activate them or get them to work as I need?

Thanks!

Comment: You are adding controls. These controls have events. You have to write code to actually do something. It is like adding a button and say *i click it and nothing happens*. If you dont bother dont create vertical and horizontal scrollbars. Just set true to AutoScroll property of your Form

Comment: Can you explain why you need those manually added scroll bars? You can get a panel to scroll by setting `AutoScroll` property.

Comment: I tried this already, drag and drop the scroll bars, change the AutoScroll to true, but it's not working

Comment: Delete your scrollbar controls and just set the container's AutoScroll property to true.

Comment: I have been tried this, just setting AutoScroll = true..still dose'nt works

Comment: In order to see the scrollbars you must obviously have some controls outside of the container area. If you dont no scrollbars will appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't add Scrollbars; you set `AutoScroll = true` in the form's property panel.

Now when any control grows out of the `Form` or is moved over right or bottom border the `Form` will show the necessary `Scrollbar`.

You can test it with a `Label` and a `TextBox`: Set the `Label` to the right border and script the `TextBox`'s `TextChanged` event like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Now run the programm and enter stuff into the `Textbox`; you will observe how the `Label` grows and how the `Form` brings up a horizontal `Scrollbar` when it goes over the edge.

Note 1: This will not work if the `Form` has `AutoSize = true` - then instead the form will grow! If the `Form` has both `AutoSize` and `AutoScroll` true, then `AutoSize` will win.

Note 2: This test will only work if the `Label` has `AutoSize = true`, as it has by default..

Comment: I tried this, the form autoScroll is true the autoSize is false..some labels get out of the form bcause of they size but scrollBar dosent brought up.. There are AutoScrollSize and AutoScrollMargin property, its matter what they eqauls to?

Comment: Their defaults should do. Is the label docked?

Comment: good. however there is something not right with your programm as it is. please try this out with a __completely fresh form__ and you will see that the only things you need to do is set the forms autoscroll to true and place/grow a control over the border.. once you see that you can go back and search for the things that are wrong/different in your real form..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Panel` control as container of your child controls and set "`AutoScroll`" property to `true`.

Set `true` to `AutoScroll` property of `Form`.

Write this code in your Form `Load Event`, and you will get your scroll bar, like I am writing it here in my Form Load Event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Panel my_panel = new Panel();
    VScrollBar vScroller = new VScrollBar();
    vScroller.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
    vScroller.Width = 30;
    vScroller.Height = 200;
    vScroller.Name = "VScrollBar1";
   my_panel.Controls.Add(vScroller);
}
```

Comment: try to add a Panel container and use the snippet code i suggested

Comment: Dosent work..When some simple text is very long and get out of the frame the scroll dosent work

Answer (score 0):

vScrollbars and hScrollbars are just plain controls without code. [UI]

You need to code to make them do something!

Or just set the property 'AutoScroll = true;' in your form **or** add a panel and set it to true.

However your control needs Focus() to scroll with your mouse wheel.

**Here is a little workaround:**

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Works for panels, richtextboxes, 3rd party etc..
    Application.AddMessageFilter(new ScrollableControls(panel1, richtextbox1, radScrollablePanel1.PanelContainer));
}
```

**ScrollableControls.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//Let controls scroll without Focus();

namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    internal struct ScrollableControls : IMessageFilter
    {
        private const int WmMousewheel = 0x020A;
        private readonly Control[] _controls;

        public ScrollableControls(params Control[] controls)
        {
            _controls = controls;
        }

        bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg != WmMousewheel) return false;
            foreach (var item in _controls)
            {
                ScrollControl(item, ref m);
            }
            return false;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        private static void ScrollControl(Control control, ref Message m)
        {
            if (control.RectangleToScreen(control.ClientRectangle).Contains(Cursor.Position) && control.Visible)
            {
                SendMessage(control.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam.ToInt32(), m.LParam.ToInt32());
            }
        }
    }
}
```